# spring load resources conditionally

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I want to use JS to load another JS file from a server but i want to do it conditionally example if the userId sent by the request is in my database send back the file.
So i thought of creating an interceptor.
Is there a better way to do it because an interceptor would be an overkill?

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <bean class="com.mycomp.webservice.UserInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

public class UserInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Override
@Transactional
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        if(!userService.userPresent(request)){

            return false;
        }   
        else{
            return true;
        }

}
```

Edit: So i figured out that the question isn't that clear. the file i want to upload is part of the static resources so i don' want to just load it to the client, i want to cache it as well.
So i leave you with [a link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).

Edit 2: So this is what i ended up doing. under my mvc-resources config i created an interceptor to handle request for protected static resources.

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/static/protected/**" />
        <bean class="com.mycompany.interceptor.ProtectedResourcesInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

public class ProtectedResourcesInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    if("your condition is true") {
        System.out.println("Access Granted to protected resources");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

The interceptor will handle requests to /static/protected and if conditions are right it will serve it. If anyone has a cleaner solution please share it.

Comment: How are you loading your JS-File? The Problem with that interceptor would be that it would fire on all of your request. So it would be better to bind your condition to one endpoint.

Comment: I think I don't understand the problem correctly. You should have created a `controller` which returns the JS. In this controller you could do your validation. You can bind the request as an argument in your controller Method and call it like described.